# Cannot read property 'name' of null in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
if (command === "info") {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const status2 = message.author.presence.status;
    const games2 = message.author.presence.game.name;
    const untaggedembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor(0xE69A49)
        .addField("Account Username:", `${message.author.username}#${message.author.tag}`)
        .addField("User ID:", message.author.id)
        .addField("Discord user was created on:", message.author.createdAt.toDateString())
        .addField("Discord user joined on:", message.guild.joinedAt.toDateString())
        .addField("Playing: ", games2 !== null ? games2 : "None", true)
        .addField("Last Message: ", message.author.lastMessage !== null ? message.author.lastMessage : "None", true)
        .addField("User Status: ", status2)
    if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.channel.sendEmbed(untaggedembed)
    if (!user === '@Robot Hamster') return message.channel.send("Can't get info for Robot Hamster ")
    const status = user.presence.status;
    const games = user.presence.game.name;
    // If a user is tagged
    const taggedembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL)
        .setColor(0xE69A49)
        .setDescription("This is " + user.username + "'s" + " Discord Info!")
        .addField("Account Username:", `${user.username}#${user.discriminator}`)
        .addField("User ID:", user.id)
        .addField("Is this User a Bot [T/F]: ", user.bot)
        .addField("Discord user was created on:", user.createdAt.toDateString())
        .addField("Discord user joined on:", message.guild.joinedAt.toDateString())
    addField("Playing: ", games !== null ? games : "None", true)
    .addField("Last Message: ", user.lastMessage !== null ? user.lastMessage : "None", true)
    .addField("User Status: ", status)
    .setFooter("Requested by: " + message.author.username) message.channel.sendEmbed(taggedembed);
}
```

im getting Cannot read property 'name' of null at the addField("Playing: ", games !== null ? games : "None", true) not to sure whats the issue but any help would be appreciated as im lost

Comment: according to the error message, it refers to different place in code where you try to read message.author.presence.game.name on 4th line or user.presence.game.name later below (so either message.author.presence.game or user.presence.game is null)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (command === "info") {
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
const status2 = message.author.presence.status;
const games2 = message.author.presence.game.name;
const untaggedembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
    .setColor(0xE69A49)
    .addField("Account Username:", `${message.author.username}#${message.author.tag}`)
    .addField("User ID:", message.author.id)
    .addField("Discord user was created on:", message.author.createdAt.toDateString())
    .addField("Discord user joined on:", message.guild.joinedAt.toDateString())
    .addField("Playing: ", games2 !== null ? games2 : "None", true)
    .addField("Last Message: ", message.author.lastMessage !== null ? message.author.lastMessage : "None", true)
    .addField("User Status: ", status2)
if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.channel.sendEmbed(untaggedembed)
if (!user === '@Robot Hamster') return message.channel.send("Can't get info for Robot Hamster ")
const status = user.presence.status;
const games = user.presence.game.name;
// If a user is tagged
const taggedembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL)
    .setColor(0xE69A49)
    .setDescription("This is " + user.username + "'s" + " Discord Info!")
    .addField("Account Username:", `${user.username}#${user.discriminator}`)
    .addField("User ID:", user.id)
    .addField("Is this User a Bot [T/F]: ", user.bot)
    .addField("Discord user was created on:", user.createdAt.toDateString())
    .addField("Discord user joined on:", message.guild.joinedAt.toDateString())
.addField("Playing: ", games !== null ? games : "None", true)
.addField("Last Message: ", user.lastMessage !== null ? user.lastMessage : "None", true)
.addField("User Status: ", status)
.setFooter("Requested by: " + message.author.username) message.channel.sendEmbed(taggedembed);
```

Does that work? I guess it should work.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: The problem was, code maker didn't put . to .addField("Playing: ", games !== null ? games : "None", true)

Comment: you should add that to your answer and get rid of the rest of the code as your answer is unreadable